# Replace Last character in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL server 2008, and facing problem about character replacement.

If I use

```
SELECT REPLACE(MYWORD,0,1) FROM MYTABLE
```

It is replacing all 0 into 1, I just want to replace Last character Like `MYWORD = "ERMN0"` so it will be `MYWORD = "ERMN1"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

using `STUFF`, which, IMO, ends up being most readable:

```
DECLARE @MyWORD VARCHAR(20) = 'ABCDEF123'

SELECT STUFF(@MyWORD, LEN(@MyWORD), 1, '2')
```

output:

```
ABCDEF122
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use combination of `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `CASE`.
You need to use `CASE` to check the most `RIGHT` character whether it's a `0` or not and replace it with `1`. And at last, combine it with the `LEFT` part (after being separated from the last character) of the `MYWORD` string.

However, depending on your requirement, it may have a drawback.
When there is a word ending with `10`, it would also be replaced.

```
SELECT LEFT(MYWORD,LEN(MYWORD)-1) + CASE RIGHT(MYWORD,1) WHEN '0' THEN '1' ELSE RIGHT(MYWORD,1) END
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT LEFT('ERMN0', Len('ERMN0')-1)
       + Replace(RIGHT('ERMN0', 1), 0, 1)
```

**OUTPUT : ERMN1**

In your case

```
SELECT LEFT(MYWORD, Len(MYWORD)-1)
       + Replace(RIGHT(MYWORD, 1), 0, 1) as [REPLACED] FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
SELECT LEFT ('ERMN0' , Len('ERMN0') -1 ) + REPLACE(Right('ERMN0', 1), '0','1')
```

Or in your case

```
SELECT LEFT (MYWORD , Len(MYWORD) -1 ) + REPLACE(Right(MYWORD, 1), '0','1') AS MYWORD FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MYWORD, 1, LEN(MYWORD) - 1) +
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(MYWORD, LEN(MYWORD), LEN(MYWORD)), 0, 1) FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

this is also use full to replace letters from end

It is used from replacing characters from end 1,2 or N

```
 Declare @Name nvarchar(20) = 'Bollywood' 
select @Name = REPLACE(@Name, SUBSTRING(@Name, len(@Name) - 1, 2), 'as') 
SELECT @Name
```

output is "Bollywoas"

- Here best part is you can repalce as many character from last you needed.