# Issue with replace function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle12c

I want to replace 6 of the last 10 digits in a string with XXXXXX. The length of the string can be 16 or 19.

Using below query:

```
SELECT REPLACE('0000000000000000000',SUBSTR('0000000000000000000',-10,6), 'XXXXXX') FROM DUAL;
--Actual Output  --XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0
--Expected Output--000000000XXXXXX0000

SELECT REPLACE('1234561234561234561',SUBSTR('1234561234561234561',-10,6), 'XXXXXX') FROM DUAL;
--Actual Output  --123XXXXXXXXXXXX4561
--Expected Output--123456123XXXXXX4561

SELECT REPLACE('0004421640006525212',SUBSTR('0004421640006525212',-10,6), 'XXXXXX') FROM DUAL;
--Actual Output  --000442164XXXXXX5212
--Expected Output--000442164XXXXXX5212
```

Why do the first two give the wrong result, and how can I fix the query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace Last character in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647039/replace-last-character-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2):

If the length of the string was always 19 you could do:

```
substr('0004421640006525212', 1, 9) || 'XXXXXX' || substr('0004421640006525212', -4)
```

With two possible lengths you could use a case expression to decide the second argument for the first `substr()` call, based on the actual string length; or you could allow for any length (of at least 10, anyway) with:

```
substr('0004421640006525212', 1, length('0004421640006525212') - 10) || 'XXXXXX' || substr('0004421640006525212', -4)
```

or with a placeholder/column for brevity:

```
substr(str, 1, length(str) - 10) || 'XXXXXX' || substr(str, -4)
```

Or maybe simpler, but slower, you could use a regular expression:

```
regexp_replace('0004421640006525212', '^(.*?)(.{6})(.{4})$', '\1XXXXXX\3')
```

The regular expression splits the string into three groups; working backwards, `(.{4})$` is a group of exactly four characters at the end of the string; then `(.{6})` is a group of exactly six characters (the ones you want to replace); then `^(.*}` is a group of any/all the remaining characters from the start of the string. The replacement pattern keeps the first and third groups - with `\1` and `\3` - and puts the fixed Xs between those. The second group - of six characters - is discarded.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25d8ea/1) getting the values, and a couple of shorter ones, form a table to avoid having to repeat them all; which also shows the first version doesn't work properly with varying lengths.

---

The replace function replaces every occurrence of one string with another.  It doesn't know or care how the second argument is generated; it doesn't know you're getting it from a particular position in the same string.

When you do:

```
REPLACE('0004421640006525212',SUBSTR('0004421640006525212',-10,6), 'XXXXXX')
```

the `SUBSTR()` evaluates to '000652', so it's effectively:

```
REPLACE('0004421640006525212','000652', 'XXXXXX')
```

and that does what you want, because that substring only appears once in the original string. But with:

```
REPLACE('1234561234561234561',SUBSTR('1234561234561234561',-10,6), 'XXXXXX')
```

the `SUBSTR()` evaluates to '456123', so it's effectively:

```
REPLACE('1234561234561234561','456123', 'XXXXXX')
```

and that appears multiple times in the original string:

```
1234561234561234561
   ^^^^^^
         ^^^^^^
```

and *both* of those are replaced. With all zeros it's even worse; the `SUBSTR()` is now '000000', so it matches three times:

```
0000000000000000000
^^^^^^
      ^^^^^^
            ^^^^^^
```

and all three of those are replaced.